# Why does the instance method `hashCode` on `java.lang.Integer` make an extra jump to the static class method to simply return its own integer value?

Tags: java, method-hiding

I was just exploring different kinds of implementations to the hashCode() method. I opened up the java.lang.Integer class and found this implementation for hashCode():

```
public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(value);
}

public static int hashCode(int value) {
        return value;
}
```

My question is, why can't the implementation be as simple as:

```
public int hashCode(){
    return this.value;
}
```

What is the need to create an additional static method to pass around the value and return the same? Am I overlooking any important detail here?

Comment: I guess the main reason for the static hashCode method was that it is also public. In order not to duplicate the (admittedly trivial) implementation it is used by the instance method as well.

Comment: The static method gives you a possibility to get a hashCode for a primitive int. int has no hashCode() method of its own. This way you don't have to write new Integer(int).hashCode(). And the first method refers to the second so that you have only one place that "computes" the hashCode.

Comment: In addition, there is probably no performance impact in practice, as even if an implementation should not have intrinsics for this, it should be easily optimizeable (inlining etc.)

Comment: Possibly for backwards compatibility?

Comment: @BasilBourque any suggestions for the title?

Comment: @RalfRenz while I partially I agree with you, why would the primitive int require a hashCode()? It is not an object.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't know what backwards compatibility is. Can you explain?

Comment: Backwards compatibility means that code written with the Java 1 interpreter in mind will run on Java 8, 9, 10, 11, etc.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc what is happening here that wasn't in the earlier versions?

Comment: I notice on the Javadoc for the static method [`java.lang.Integer.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode(int)) that it was **added in Java 8**. The [source code in Java 14](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) has no explanation for its creation. I wonder if the static method was needed for some new feature in Java 8, something like streams?

Answer (score 1):

That code does look odd when viewed on its own.

But notice that the static method [`java.lang.Integer.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode(int)):

- was added later, in Java 8
- is `public`

The [source code in Java 14](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) shows no comments to explain why this static method was added. Because the method is `public`, I presume this new static method plays a part in some new feature in Java 8, perhaps related to streams, called elsewhere in the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) codebase.

As noted in the Javadoc, the source code of the existing [`Integer::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode()) instance method was rewritten to call the static `hashCode` simply for consistency. This way there is only one place where the hash code is actually being generated. Having [only one place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is wise for review and maintenance of the codebase.

Making `hashCode` static is certainly unusual. The purpose of the `hashCode` method is to identify one object of that class to another for use in collections such as [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) or [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html). Given that we are comparing instances by the method, it makes sense for `hashCode` to be an instance method rather than static.

The optimizing compiler such as [*HotSpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) or [*OpenJ9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) is likely to inline the `hashCode` method calls, making moot the instance-method versus static-method arrangement in source code.

Answer (score 1):

@Basil Bourque's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62963608/139985) covers just about everything.  But he leaves open the question of why the `public static void hashCode(int)` was added.

The change was made in this changeset in November 2012

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/be1fb42ef696/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java

The title and summary for the changeset say this:

> *7088913: Add compatible static hashCode(primitive) to primitive wrapper classes*
>
> *Summary: Adds static utility methods to each primitive wrapper class to allow calculation of a hashCode value from an unboxed primitive.*

Note that the changeset does not document the motivation for the change.

I infer that one purpose of the enhancement is to avoid the application programmer having to know how the primitive wrapper classes are computed.  Prior to Java 8, to compute the wrapper-compatible hash code for a primitive `int`, the programmer would have to have written either

```
  int value = ...
  int hash = ((Integer) value).hashCode();  // Facially inefficient (depending on
                                            // JIT compiler's ability to get
                                            // rid of the box/unbox sequence)
```

or

```
  int value = ...
  int hash = value;                         // Hardwires knowledge of how 
                                            // Integer.hashCode() is computed.
```

While the "knowledge" is trivial for `int` / `Integer`, consider the case of `double` / `Double` where the hash code computation is:

```
  long bits = doubleToLongBits(value);
  return (int)(bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
```

---

It seems likely that this changeset was *also* motivated by the Streams project; e.g. so that `Integer::hashCode` can be used in a stream of integers.

However, the [changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/1d918647332e/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) that added `sum`, `min` and `max` for use in stream reductions happened a couple of months after this one.  So we cannot definitively make the connection ... based on this evidence.